# Python list types

Tags: python, list, types, integer

This is quite a weird/silly question so if anyone as a better title name, please request an edit.

I've created a function that returns the product of numbers in a list.
When testing this function, I tried lists that that included intergers and reals(floats), such as `items = [1,2.0,3,4.0]`

Function:

```
items = [1.0, 2, 3.0, 10, "a"]

def mult1(items):
    total = 1
    for i in items:
            total = total * i
    return total

print mult1(items)
```

This function above works with items being [1.0, 2, 3.0, 10] and the output of that particular list being 60.0.

I've studied Standard ML where you can only generally have a list of a particular type (I'm sure there's code out there that somehow makes my statement irrelevant), so intrigued to find out what would happen if I entered a string as a list item, I did, and got an error (I expected to get an error because you can't multiply a string with a number).

However, the error I received has confused me:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

This error has confused me. I understand that a string cannot be multiplied, but does this also suggest that all of the items in the list are considered a float despite some looking like integers?

I thought that the error should suggest it cannot compute a type that is not a float or not an integer, but to me (probably wrong) it seems like it's suggesting that it can't multiply the list by a a type that is not an integer that is also not of type float?

To me this sounds like each element has two types, integer and float.

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote that generates this error?

Comment: Show us the function as normal function would work fine

Comment: I will add code for my function

Comment: Multiplying a list by `n` gives you `n` of that list.  If you want to multiple each item in the list use something like: `map(lambda x: x*2, [1, 2,3, 4])`

Comment: @chown I have made three versions of my loop, one with a for loop, one with recursion and one with reduce :)

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because you are (perhaps unintentionally) multiplying a sequence (`list`, `str`, `tuple`) by a `float`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> a * 2
[1, 2, 1, 2]
>>> a * 2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply a string but only by an int, you see the error as you are trying to multiply a string by a float:

```
In [7]: "foo" * 2
Out[7]: 'foofoo'

In [8]: "foo" * 2.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-3128e6ce951c> in <module>()
----> 1 "foo" * 2.

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

In your particular case you are trying to multiply `a` from your list by a float:

```
 [1.0, 2, 3.0, 10, "a"] 
                    ^
                   error
```

Total starts out an int but when you  multiply an int by a float you get a float so  `total = total * 1.0 -> 1.0`:

```
In [9]: 1 * 1.0
Out[9]: 1.0
```

Comment: My function is to find the product of a list though, so using a list such as [1, "a, 2, "b"] does not work

Comment: @ChrisMulheron, there is no possible that a float * a_str can ever work, what would `1.23456 * "foo"` output?

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now, so once an integer is multiplied by a float, are the rest of the number in the items in the list considered a float as well? even if they look like an integer? or does python just know that if it's an integer to convert that integer to a float once calculating?

Comment: @ChrisMulheronm yes, I added an example, once you multiply total by a float you get a float returned

Comment: I'm definitely over complicating things, apologies, just trying to be thorough

Comment: No worries,  better to ask if you are unsure

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because you can actually multiply some non-number types by ints, but not by floats. So if your `product` function looks something like:

```
def product(l):
    prod = l[0]
    for x in l[1:]:
        prod *= x
    return prod
```

and your list looks like this : `l = ['this string',3,2.0]`

then your iterations will show the following:

```
>>> def product(l):
    prod = l[0]
    for x in l[1:]:
        prod *= x
        print(prod)
    return prod

>>> l = ['this string',3,2.0]
>>> product(l)
this stringthis stringthis string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#69>", line 1, in <module>
    product(l)
  File "<pyshell#67>", line 4, in product
    prod *= x
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

note that the first iteration is allowed because `str*int` is a valid expression (so is `list*int` and `tup*int` etc) and so `prod` is still valid but is a STRING, not an int or float. then when you DO try to do a `str*float` expression, the `TypeError` will occur.